# Trouble with inline keyword in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a function which could take both ints and floats as parameters. The problem is that the compiler automatically infers the type because of a number in the function despite using the inline keyword. Here's what I mean:

```fs
(* Infers ints for every parameter because of '1' *)
let inline Lerp a b t = (1 - t) * a + t * b
(* Infers floats for every parameter because I added '.0' to '1' *)
let inline Lerp' a b t = (1.0 - t) * a + t * b
```

I can create two separate functions but it's kind of disappointing. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne`, which resolves to the value 'one' for any primitive numeric type or any type with a static member called 'One':

```ml
let inline Lerp a b t =
  (LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne - t) * a + t * b

Lerp 1 2 3 |> printfn "%A"         // 4
Lerp 1.1 2.2 3.3 |> printfn "%A"   // 4.73
```

Comment: I suppose it works in my case, but what if I used a different number? Is there a generic number type that could be used?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can build other generic numbers from Zero and One.

Comment: You have to make sure your arithmetic is all generic, instead of using integers. So you could do `let two = GenericOne + GenericOne`. To be systematic, you could even create other numbers using [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Arithmetic), by defining addition as repeated succession, then defining multiplication as repeated addition, etc.

Comment: Yeah I figured :). Sorry for deleting the comment.

Comment: Actually, the code I suggested doesn't seem to work, so it's not quite as simple as I thought. I'll see if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: It works as long as all the parameters are of the same type. In this case `a` and `b` would be integers and `t` would be a float, but that wasn't explicitly stated in my question, that's why I still marked the answer as a solution. I ended up just making an extra function that converted the first two values into a float. If you can find a better solution though, it would be highly appreciated.